# Smart-pointer as reference of a container

Tags: list, reference, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have two classes:

tcp_server and tcp_connection
tcp_server has a list of tcp_connection pointer objects, and the way I am doing is passing this list by pointer to tcp_connection, which will take care of joining and removing itself from the list on the destroyer.

tcp_server:

```
private:
std::list<std::weak_ptr<tcp_connection>> connections;

// passing reference to the tcp_connection
new_connection->join(&connections);
```

tcp_connection:

```
private:
std::list<std::weak_ptr<tcp_connection>>* connections;

public
void join(std::list<std::weak_ptr<tcp_connection>>* con)
{
    connections = con;
    connections->push_back(shared_from_this());
}
```

Ok. Everything works well at this point; however if I try to delete connections pointer on tcp_connection destroyer, server crashes.

I tried to mess with smart pointers, but I got lost on it. Do I create a unique_ptr on tcp_server method before passing it to JOIN, and pass as reference to tcp_connection with a std::move?

Any ideas how to make it more efficient?